# There is error in console when I use spring-boot-starter-data-redis

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

springboot version:2.3.6

I writing some "dependency" into pom.xml and configure it.

"dependency" as shown below:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

and application.yml context is:

```
  redis:
    host: exampleHost.
    port: 6379
    password: examplePwd
    timeout: 10s
    jedis:
      pool:
        min-idle: 0
        max-idle: 8
        max-active: 8
        max-wait: -1ms
```

when I use **jedis**,no Error.

But,Error will appear when I use **lettuce**.

```
  redis:
    host: exampleHost.
    port: 6379
    password: examplePwd
    timeout: 10s
    lettuce:
      pool:
        min-idle: 0
        max-idle: 8
        max-active: 8
        max-wait: -1ms
```

Why is that?  Bug?  Feature? Or other?

Here are some error at the console.

Actually, `commons-pool2` included at `spring-data-redis`'s pom

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPoolConfig
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you share the error message you are seeing?

Comment: Sure.
I have added the main error message to the question

Comment: You should know that in your example, the pool does not work, because the pool will work if you provide a redis cluster or redis sentinel configuration. You configuration for standalone mode;